How to automatically assign proper IP addresses in libvirt network
Trying to make a virtual network that contains a single VM. Packets are routed through the host with <forward mode="route" />.
I've read a bunch of stuff online and AFAIK it comes down to this section of the XML file:
<ip address="...." netmask="....">
....
</ip>

In all the examples I've seen they specify a certain IP address and corresponding address range to use for the gateway and for IP delegation, respectively. I'd much rather just have the host system check which ranges are unused by any other interfaces and simply use one.
For IPv4 it's not really a big deal. If it's not possible I'll just hardcode some numbers in there and tell my router to always use a specific separate subnet.
For IPv6 it's more difficult, because as I gather, I should specify the global scope IPv6 in there (because I'm using the "route" forwarding mode). My ISP doesn't make any guarantees about what global IPv6 address prefixes it gives me. I get what I get, and I need to somehow propagate that down to the virtual network so that the VM can still be on the internet.
If this doesn't work I guess I'll have to put the VM behind a NAT. That way I can work with link-local addresses that don't have to be subject to change. Maybe the NAT method would also be more secure? Not sure about that, I'd appreciate some input.
Anyway, yeah, that's my situation. How would you handle that? What's my next move?

But if the host chose a range at random, wouldn't you have to tell the router about it every single time instead of just once?
